# Why does my json file contain these symbols?

Tags: python, json, character-encoding

I have a file which is supposed to be a json, however I cannot decode it without running into some error because of these symbols.

This is what the first line of file looks like when I open it in Notepad (sensitive data has been replaced with the `...`). The first symbol seems to be `~ÿ}#c`

```
~ÿ}#c{ "msg_type" : "measurement", "msg_schema" : 2, "receiver" : { ... (})~~ÿ}#c{ Ü–".
```

These symbols seem to only exist in between the start/end of a bracket structure. AFAIK the rest of the file seems ok, it's just these characters that prevent me from reading the data.
**How can I remove these symbols so I can read the file?**

Comment: "I have a file which is supposed to be a json" - according to whom? Where did it come from? "sensitive data has been replaced with the ..." - this obscures the structure of the data. Is it possible to get a sample that does not contain sensitive data, and is small but **complete**? "How can I remove these symbols so I can read the file?" - well, do you know any ways to remove text from a string? What exactly confuses you about applying those techniques?

Comment: I suspect this is a binary file that happend to include JSON in it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the issue is these symbols all appear different so it's not as simple as doing a find and delete. Unfortunately I do not have any small or complete data to show. Just want to know what these symbols are and if there was some general way of removing said symbols.

Comment: They don't look like any particular, standard thing, no. Again: **where did the file come from**? Is there documentation of the format? Is there evidence to say that these "symbols" are there intentionally (rather than because the file was corrupted)?